# Firestore response interceptor

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

My Vue2 app works letting users sign in with Google accounts (through firebase auth) and registering them in a 'users' collection in firestore, also these users are given management permissions by an admin user.

Now, although every user have read permissions based on their user type I want to be **listening for 'permission-denied' errors** so I know security was compromised somehow and **make them login again**. I know I can do it like this in any request:

```
firestore.collection('users').get().then(() => {
        console.log('success')
    }, () => { // catch
        this.logout()
    }
})
```

, but I'd be a pain in the ass implementing this in every request and I am pretty sure there must be a better way to do it, like an error interceptor that I probably missed in the documentation.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: I think it is almost the same as my intent since I'd have to implement it in any request I wish to listen to.
Gonna try implementing a kind of wrapper and see if it works. Thanks anyway.